# How to "make" TREC_EVAL in windows 8.1 64 bit machine?

Tags: windows, makefile

I am new to using trec_eval program, and want to generate the binary of it in Windows 8.1 64 bit machine.

I tried using GNU make command to create the binary of it, but I get the following error :
[image: Error log]

Note : I tried the same from Cygwin 64 bit terminal on my system, but it failed too.

Is it not possible to do this in Windows at all ?

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified" probably means that `gcc` is not found. Check that you have gcc installed and it can be called from Cygwin using simple `gcc`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : Thanks for the guidance, I added the GCC compiler 4.9.3 to the cygwin terminal, and now I get some syntax erros in the make process. Should I post the screenshot ?

Comment: It is better to copy **text** from the terminal and paste it into the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : the error log is too big for me to efficiently copy it here

Comment: You can redirect all output into the file, then copy text from that file. In any case it would be  better than screenshot.